# Munin node not showing up in overview

Tags: port, munin

I have `munin` and `munin-node` installed on a "master" server, (lets call it **server1**) and `munin-node` installed on a second server (let's call that one **server2**)

I am fairly certain that my configuration files are correct, but I can't get the second server to show!  This is irritating because reading -man and Google-ing, Munin is not rocket science!  I must be missing something simple.

**server1**'s hostname: `server1.com`  --  ip address: `10.2.6.60`

**server2**'s hostname: `server2` (without the `.com`)  --  ip address: `10.2.6.80`

**server1.com**'s config **/etc/munin/munin.conf**:

```
[server1.com]
    address 127.0.0.1
    use_node_name yes

[server2]
    address 10.2.6.80
    use_node_name_yes
```

**server2**'s configuration `/etc/munin/munin-node.conf`

```
log_level 4
log_file /var/log/munin/munin-node.log
pid_file /var/run/munin/munin-node.pid

background 1
setsid 1

user root
group root

ignore_file [\#~]$
ignore_file DEADJOE$
ignore_file \.bak$
ignore_file %$
ignore_file \.dpkg-(tmp|new|old|dist)$
ignore_file \.rpm(save|new)$
ignore_file \.pod$

host_name server1.com
allow ^10\.2\.6\.60$

host *

port 4949
```

Here's my telnet to **server2** from **server1**

```
telnet 10.2.6.80 4949
Trying 10.2.6.80...
Connected to 10.2.6.80.
Escape character is '^]'.
# munin node at server1.com
```

**server2** log (you'll notice the last two entries -- those are my `telnet` attempts, however you'll notice that there's no other connection attempts by munin itself):

```
2017/02/15-17:43:18 Munin::Node::Server (type Net::Server::Fork) starting! pid(33478)
Resolved [*]:4949 to [::]:4949, IPv6
Not including resolved host [0.0.0.0] IPv4 because it will be handled by [::] IPv6
Binding to TCP port 4949 on host :: with IPv6
Setting gid to "0 0"
2017/02/15-17:44:03 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[::ffff:10.2.6.60]:40924" Local: "[::ffff:10.2.6.80]:4949"
2017/02/15-17:52:25 CONNECT TCP Peer: "[::ffff:10.2.6.60]:40928" Local: "[::ffff:10.2.6.80]:4949"
```

I'm stumped!!

Answer (score 3):

Did you resolve this situation? I believe the issue is in the **server2** configuration file. In this file, one finds the line:

```
host_name server1.com
```

This line should either be "server2" or commented out if the hostname returns the correct information.

(from [munin-node.conf](http://guide.munin-monitoring.org/en/latest/reference/munin-node.conf.html)):

> **host_name:** The hostname used by munin-node to present itself to the munin master. Use this if the local node name differs from the name configured in the munin master.

The issue may be seen in the telnet output to **server2** from **server1**, and it reports:

```
# munin node at server1.com
```

It should report server2.

If you look in the log files on **server1** at `/var/log/munin/munin-update.log`, there may have been an entry similar to:

```
2017/08/15 16:35:02 [INFO] node server2 advertised itself as server1.com instead.
```